# MS Jet Oledb What Type Of Source Is ComSys?

Tags: .net, database, oledb, jet

I am trying to understand using of variety of databases for research, recently I've been studying Jet OLEDB. In some source code I saw this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=ComSys;
```

What is this ComSys? Is it a path To somewhere? If so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the name of a data source, as configured in Control Panel + Administrative Tools + Data Sources (ODBC).  The DSN specifies the ODBC driver and whatever config it needs.  Like the path to the .mdb for the Jet driver.  The actual config data is stored in the registry and found back at runtime through the data source name.  So you don't have to hardcode anything about the database in your code and can leave it up to the admin to setup and adjust the mapping.